# Detecting when a client disconnects with Django and Server-Sent Events on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, server-sent-events

Heroku's documentation about [sending a streaming response](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#longpolling-and-streaming-responses) says:

> "If you’re sending a streaming response, such as with server-sent
>   events, you’ll need to detect when the client has hung up, and make
>   sure your app server closes the connection promptly. "

I've been experimenting on Heroku with Server-Sent Events in Django, using [django-sse](https://github.com/niwibe/django-sse). It uses an iterator that loops forever, reading messages from a Redis pub/sub channel and sending them to the client:

```
def iterator(self):
    connection = _connect()
    pubsub = connection.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe(self.get_redis_channel())

    for message in pubsub.listen():
        if message['type'] == 'message':
            event, data = json.loads(message['data'])
            self.sse.add_message(event, data)
            yield
```

The problem is that I would like to break out of this loop if the client disconnects, so I can close the connection to Redis. How can I detect when the client disconnects?

Comment: Are you sure that the connection doesn't close automatically? You can use the `CLIENT LIST` command in `redis-cli` to check if the django redis client is still connected.

Comment: It doesn't on Heroku (though it did when I ran it locally). I first noticed the problem when I ran out of Redis connections even though I was the only one using my test site (the free RedisToGo plan has a max of 10 connections.) I later confirmed with `redis-cli` and `CLIENT LIST` that indeed the connections were not closing automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with a Scala Play2 application on Heroku that wouldn't detect when an SSE connection was being closed by the client on either close() or refresh or window closing. Enabling the new [Heroku Labs websockets feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets) fixed this for me.

An update:

I asked Heroku support and told them about my experience. This was their reply.

> Hi Lloyd,
>
> This is a known issue, and you are correct that the new WebSocket
>   endpoints fix the problem. We don't plan to address the problem in
>   existing endpoints, but we will eventually rollout the WebSocket
>   endpoints to a wider audience.
>
> Best,
>
> Jake